# É possível DomPDF executar código PHP?

Tags: php, html5, dompdf

Tenho que executar alguns comandos em php para gerar uma tabela ,após isso, eu armazeno esse resultado em uma variável executo o comando echo e a tabela é mostrada na tela. O problema é quando tento executar isso no DomPDF, quando tento executar:

```
$dompdf->load_html( // variável que contem a tabela ->$r);`
```

O pdf é gerado mas sem nenhuma informação dentro,como faço para resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Depende muito do seu html, essas bibliotecas pra php para geração de pdf normalmente são bem limitadas em questão de renderização de html, recentemente utilizei o mpdf e sofri bastante com esse tipo de problema. Aconselho utilizar o ChromePdf(https://github.com/abalozz/chrome-pdf-php), ele utiliza as APIs do chrome para fazer várias coisas, inclusive gerar pdf como se fosse imprimir a página.

Comment: Ele gera o pdf a partir de uma URL, sem levar em consideração o código ?"

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância ,mas como funciona o instalação ?

Comment: Eu respondi a isso na sua pergunta anterior.

Comment: É possível, desde que você use um buffer de saída, veja lá.

Comment: É eu realmente n entendi o processo de instalação. "sou bem leigo"

Comment: baixe os arquivos ,coloquei no mesmo diretório da pagina q iria utilizar , quando vou ver no navegador acontecer esse erro :  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Nuzkito\ChromePdf\ChromePdf' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Flex\pf.php on line 69
( ! ) Error: Class 'Nuzkito\ChromePdf\ChromePdf' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Flex\pf.php on line 69